# What is good design and style practice regarding use of attr and visibility (e.g. private, public)?

Tags: ruby, oop

So I understand that the *attr* syntax sugar in ruby translates into just defining instance variables and methods for writing/reading them.

What I'm wanting to know is, what are the best practices for design if you are trying to keep your class public interfaces minimal? Should you avoid attr_accessor like unless very clearly public? How do attr_writer and attr_reader fit into public/private visibility?

If it makes sense, say, to use attr_reader for private fields that are often read, should you use attr_reader liberally and not even define the fields explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of attr methods is to let access to instance variables possible from outside of an instance. Hence, (over)use of such methods is already against object oriented programming. If you only need to access them from an instance, which is preferable from the point of view of object oriented design, you can directly refer to the instance variables:

```
@foo = 3
@foo # => 3
```

You should not need attr methods.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm asking is when you do want the instance variables accessible from outside an instance, how do you maximize privacy, and is there anything wrong with not explicitly defining such instance variables and just using accessors?

Comment: There is no difference between defining accessor methods through `attr_` class methods and directly defining them. The former is just a short way to do the latter.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by making the instance variables accessible from outside an instance while maximizing privacy. The idea is not clearly stated.

Comment: I know there's no difference to the interpreter between defining accessor methods through attr_ and directly defining. I wanted to know if it's good style to do so. The same applies to maximizing privacy (i.e. minimizing the public interface). I think you've already answered my question, which I admit is not clearly stated due to my limited ability with the language. Still learning!